# installing composer - Unsupported type Class for PhpMetaRequirement

Tags: macos, composer-php, homebrew

```
brew install josegonzalez/php/composer
```

I get the error

```
Unsupported type Class for PhpMetaRequirement
```

I am running on osx with homebrew.

Comment: +1 I would also like an answer to this! I'm going to have a play about and if I discover the answer, I'll post it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with Homebrew. Just use the standard method:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Via: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally